# Rand() producing the same results every run

Tags: c++, random, srand

I am entireley new to coding, and am coding a program to simulate catching pokemon. I have a bunch of random numbers being generated during it, but the one that randomizes which pokemon (In int main()) is not randomizing, its only producing "1". Forgive my chaotic coding.

This is the int main

```
int main(){
srand(time(0));
int Pokemon = rand() % 3 + 1;
if (Pokemon = 1)
{
    Pokemon1();
}
else if (Pokemon = 2)
{
    Pokemon2();
}
else
{
    Pokemon3();
}
return 0;
```

}

It is calling the other functions. The same thing is happening when randomizing the Pokeball, it allways chooses Ultra Ball

```
srand(time(NULL));
int BallTypeRand = rand() % 100 + 1;
if (1 < BallTypeRand < 21)
{
    BallType = 1;
    BallName = "Ultra Ball";
    BallCatchRate = 63;
}
else if (21 < BallTypeRand < 51)
{
    BallType = 2;
    BallName = "Great Ball";
    BallCatchRate = 41;
}
else 
{
    BallType = 3;
    BallName = "Poke Ball";
    BallCatchRate = 28;
}
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Headers are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime> 
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: always turn on all warnings. The compiler will show you the issue in `Pokemon = 1` and `1 < BallTypeRand < 21` immediately

Comment: TYPO assignment inside condition!

Comment: For C++ use the mechanisms provided in the `<random>` header, `srand` is a "C" left over. And with the random header you will have better control over your distributions. Doing a rand() + modular operator will not be completely random. See : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: If you are going to use `rand()` then, in most cases, you should only call `srand()` once to seed the random sequence. Use it once near the beginning of `main()`, not every time you call `rand()`.

Answer (score 2):

- `=` is an assignment operator. Use `==` operator for checking equality.
- Expressions like `1 < BallTypeRand < 21` is interpreted as `(1 < BallTypeRand) < 21`. The result of `1 < BallTypeRand` will be interpreted as 0 or 1, so this expression will always be true. You should use logical AND operator like `1 < BallTypeRand && BallTypeRand < 21`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue with the balls. Do you have any suggestions for the first issue, where the Pokémon is not randomized?

Comment: @SylviaBellefeuille I have already posted a suggestion: Use operator `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Ahh, I did not know it was refering to the main issue. That also fixed it, Dankeschön

Comment: @SylviaBellefeuille as mentioned earlier, you really, REALLY want to turn on your compiler's warnings.  Your compiler wants to point out these typos to you!

Comment: I do not know how, I am still new to it. I am using Embarcadero Dev-C++